# ConTeXt: Cross-references for Table of Contents hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, context, context-mkiv, links

## Background

Looking to customize the table of contents.

## Problem

In the example, the following problems exist:

- The last entry in the table of contents is not hyperlinked.
- All hyperlinks are off by one.

Note that the chapters and sections are separate pages in the document.

In the following image a red box surrounds the entry that cannot be clicked:

[image: Missing Link]

## Minimum Working Example

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,]
\setuphead[chapter,section][page=yes,continue=no,]

\define[3]\SectionTOC{#3 #2}

% Using alternative causes the cross-reference to be off.
\setuplist[section][
  alternative=interactive,
  command=\SectionTOC,
]

\starttext
  \placecontent

  \startchapter[title=Chapter]
    \dorecurse{4}{
      \startsection[title=Section]
        Level \recurselevel.
      \stopsection
    }
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you use an interactive alternative to generate correct hyperlinks for a customized table of contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mailing list, a `\noindent` is required to eliminate the half-line shift:

```
% The table of contents links get shifted up. This code adds a
% \noindent so that the TOC links do not get shifted.
\unprotect
\startsetups[\??listrenderings:interactive]
  \edef\p_command{\listalternativeparameter\c!command}%
  \ifx\p_command\empty
    [\currentlist: \currentlistentrynumber\space -- \currentlistentrytitle\space -- \currentlistentrypagenumber]%
  \else
    \listparameter\c!before
    \noindent\hbox \strc_lists_get_reference_attribute\v!all \strc_lists_get_destination_attribute {
      \p_command\currentlistentrynumber\currentlistentrytitle\currentlistentrypagenumber
    }
    \listparameter\c!after
  \fi
\stopsetups
\protect
```

Next, add an `\endgraf` to the lists:

```
\setuplist[chapter][
  before={\endgraf\blank[big]},
  after={\blank[medium]},
]

\setuplist[section,sectionpicture][
  before=\endgraf,
]
```